# Writing a SQL query for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have two table

table1 **tblInstruction**

```
inst_id     instruction
1               aaaaa
2               bbbbb
3               cccccc
4               ddddd
5               eeeee
6               fffff
7               ggggg
8               hhhhh
9               iiiii
10              jjjjj
```

table2 **tblDischarge**

```
d_id  inst_id1  inst_id2   inst_id3  inst_id4 
1       3          5           2        8      
2       5          7           1        10          
3       10         2           8        7      
4       6          8           4        3      
5       9          1           3        5
```

I need to get all instructions based on inst_id1,inst_id2,inst_id3,inst_id4 for d_id = 2

**Expected Output**

```
eeeee
ggggg
aaaaa
jjjjj
```

I am trying to write a SQL query to get the above output. I am using MS Access, I need to use this SQL query in a MS Access VBA program.

I tried below two SQL queries using In(), using Exists(), I got all instructions not specific instructions.

```
select instruction from tblInstruction where inst_id 
  in (select inst_id1,inst_id2,inst_id3,inst_id4 from tblDischarge where d_id = 2);

select instruction from tblInstruction where 
  exists(select inst_id1,inst_id2,inst_id3,inst_id4 from tblDischarge Where d_id = 2);
```

Comment: Please try to construct a better title, one *specific* to your question."MS Access" - we know, that's one of the tags - "SQL" - again, already better placed in a tag - "query" - almost all SQL questions will be - "help required" - we know, that's why you're asking a question on Stack Overflow. The title of your question is your chance to "sell" it to would be answerers. Given them information they won't already *know*.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the most efficient method uses `exists`:

```
select i.*
from tblInstruction as i
where exists (select 1 from tblDischarge as d where d.d_id = 2 and i.inst_id = d.inst_id1
             ) or
      exists (select 1 from tblDischarge as d where d.d_id = 2 and i.inst_id = d.inst_id2
             ) or
      exists (select 1 from tblDischarge as d where d.d_id = 2 and i.inst_id = d.inst_id3
             ) or
      exists (select 1 from tblDischarge as d where d.d_id = 2 and i.inst_id = d.inst_id4
             );
```

Note that you have a very poor data model.  It is better to have a junction table with separate rows for each instruction/discharge pair.

EDIT:

The better structure is to have a junction table `instutionDischarge`, with columns like:

- `institutionDischargeId`
- `d_id`
- `inst_id`
- `counter`  -- or something like this

Comment: Do you mean, I need to create one more table, could you please let me all three table structure. so that i can correct the model

Comment: @RaviKannan: please do not ask for free labour. Consider answers a set of hints that allow you to move forward and build more work on top. If you make a habit of asking for answers that you can type in verbatim, you are not challenging yourself as a software engineer (and potentially asking volunteer helpers for too much).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to achieve the results:-

```
select instruction from 
table1 inst1
JOIN 
(select inst_id1 as inst_id from table 2 where d_id = 2
UNION 
select inst_id2 as inst_id from table 2 where d_id = 2
UNION
select inst_id3 as inst_id from table 2 where d_id = 2
UNION
select inst_id4 as inst_id from table 2 where d_id = 2
) inst2
on inst1.inst_id  = inst2.inst_id
```